# Unreadable font keeps appearing in several programs

Tags: xfce, manjaro

I've been noticing that in several programs like Seafile, MKVToolNix, Manjaro Settings and KDEConnect (to name a few), the program is displaying in a strange font that is unreadable. I thought it might be a foreign language, but the only language  I have installed is English. I have images below to show you what I mean. Is this a known bug? Is there any way to fix it?
[image: mkvtoolnix]

Comment: what's the output of `locale -a`

Comment: The output is: 
en_US.utf8
POSIX

Comment: don't know...could try reinstalling locale/lang packages, or file permissions on locale directories, or you don't have that font, or the program may be using non-unicode font, or could be your login manager. create a vm on suspect machine and install the suspect app in the vm and see if it does the same.

Comment: Looks like [Malayalam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malayalam_script) to my untrained eye. Can you find something to copy-paste into a program that works? That would indicate whether it's a font display problem or a language problem. There do seem to be a few Latin letters thrown into the mix, which points towards a display problem. Do you have the same problem if you run a different desktop environment? Can you try under a different account?

Comment: I copied part of the messed up font and it displays in English when I paste it. I switched my DE to Openbox and the problem remains. I believe the problem is a display issue caused by a recent update because previously my fonts were displaying correctly. If it's a bug then I can downgrade the program, but I don't know what program is the culprit.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix this issue. I don't know why, but when I installed google-fonts from the AUR, the text in all of my programs began to display normally. This issue is resolved, so this can be closed now.